# Can't find wireless interface in ubuntu 15.10 on a MacBook 5,1

Tags: networking, 15.10, macbook

I've just installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my 2008 MacBook 5,1 and I cannot get the system to connect to my wireless network. I ran "ifconfig -a" and all that comes up is "lo" and "enp0s10" which is my ethernet interface. Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with the driver (or lack thereof). If you go to "System Settings" --> "Software & Updates", is the "Proprietary drivers for device (restricted)" checked?  After it is checked, go to the tab "Additional Drivers" and select the Broadcom driver (you may need to install the appropriate broadcom driver if it does not appear).  Does that do the trick?

Comment: See this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-driverslink) for installing driver